# How to add a custom package with an unusual build to a python virtual environment?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm new to virtual environments, but am required to use them for using python packages on an supercomputer that I am working on. I have a package that I wish to use, but I can't install it using `pip` in the way that I can install the other packages I need.

To build this package, I have to navigate to a particular directory and run a `./build` command, and then I am able to `import` it into python and use as normal. Is there a way to set this up within a virtual environment so that I can just `source ... activate` and the package will already be built and can be used?